# rc.local and xrandr are not working together

Tags: bash, brightness, xrandr

So I have troubles with the brightness of my screen at startup.

And it's unlucky because I tried many things to set it to right setup and only xrandr is working for me when I call this command.

```
xrandr --output eDP --brightness 1
```

On my Ubuntu I had no `/etc/rc.local` file - so I've created it and made it executable.

```
~ » ls -laht /etc | grep rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    342 lis 29 19:26 rc.local
```

Content of the file is

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

xrandr --output eDP --brightness 1

exit 0
```

when I reboot the system I get failed status on `rc-local.service`

```
~ » sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
             └─debian.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-11-29 19:27:10 CET; 14min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-rc-local-generator(8)
    Process: 920 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

lis 29 19:27:10 greenery systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
lis 29 19:27:10 greenery rc.local[924]: Can't open display
lis 29 19:27:10 greenery systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
lis 29 19:27:10 greenery systemd[1]: rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lis 29 19:27:10 greenery systemd[1]: Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

What I do wrong?

Edit 1:
When I put this into startup it doesn't work too.
[Startup config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir4kH.png)

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu you have installed ?

Comment: this can not work in my opnion. Please put your command in your autostart. so it starts with your desktop session.  This error `greenery rc.local[924]: Can't open display`

Comment: @pasmanpasmański 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @nobody about that... weird but it doesn't work too when I put it there, but command itself works if I run it in terminal

Comment: for command take `sh -c "xrandr --output eDP --brightness 1"` when you put it in your session autostart.